# Backslashes in Kornshell

Tags: ksh, backslash

I was looking over some ksh code and came across a line I didn't think would work.  Upon testing the code, it did work, but I am not sure why.

*If it matters, this is running on an AIX 5.3 system.*

The line in the code was:

```
scriptname=$(\basename $0)
```

I didn't think it would work because of the backslash in front of the `basename` command, but when I tested the `scriptname` variable, it had the correct value.

I did some further testing on the command line:

```
$ echo $(\echo test)
test
$ echo $(\echo \test)
test
$ echo $(\e\c\h\o \test)
test
$ echo `\e\c\h\o \test`
test
$ echo $(\echo "\test")
est
```

I tried it outside of the command subtitution, and it still didn't work like I thought it would:

```
$ \echo \testi\ng
testing
$ \echo "\testi\ng"
        esti
g
```

The last one is the only one that makes some sense to me.

Does Kornshell just ignore the backslashes, or maybe just convert them to the character in front of the backslash?  I assumed that putting a `\n` anywhere on the command line would be a newline, but apparently only if it is in quotes, or `\\n`.

Can someone explain what ksh does with backslashes on the command line?

Either way, I assume the better way to write the command I originally questioned would be:

```
scriptname=$(basename $0)
```

instead of:

```
scriptname=$(\basename $0)
```

Does it matter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any part of a command name is quoted then ksh will ignore any aliases when selecting what to execute.

I presume that is why the original script was using \basename.

Comment: Interesting. Are there any downsides to the backslash, other than it looks weird?

Comment: None that I know of, except for confusing those unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a related but slightly different situation.  I am editing a shell script with several rm commands written as:

```
\rm ...
```

I was wondering why the '\' was before the rm and similarly tried it only to find that it does seem to work.  Per this [site](http://www.phwinfo.com/forum/comp-unix-shell/378565-why-preceed-rm-command-backslash.html), this is done to prevent the script from accidentally using an alias (e.g. if rm is aliased to 'rm -i').  Since I found the discussion on Stack Overflow first, I thought I would add this bit in case it helps the next person out.